# Is there a free program to join and cut AVI movie files?

Tags: video, video-editing

I have a camera and it creates an AVI file every 10 minutes when recording video. I would like to join files from the camera and sometime trim part of the video. I don't want re-encode the files if possible.

Is there a free program that will let me concatenate a split AVI files?

Comment: before ask it, I read this answer. Didn't work, the command line result in a avi file with index problem. Anyway, AVITools do what I want and solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AVITools](http://www.emmgunn.com/avitools/avitoolsdownload.html) is trialware, but all it does is nag you and limit you to one job at a time.

[MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/) is another free Mac app that, despite the name, can mux together AVI, MPEG, MKV, and other sorts of video files into one big file.

And there's always good old [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html), but it isn't quite as user-friendly as the above.

Comment: HI. I didn't test AVITools before, but it is simply and is what I want, so I paid the 6 USD! Mpeg Streamclip didn't open (I am with Lion) and FFMPEG only give-me headache. I have tried it before, but the result wasn't good. Pay was faster than learn how to do the correct way.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the `concat` demuxer with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i <(for f in $PWD/*.avi;do echo "file '$f'";done) -c copy output.avi
```

`-c copy` disables re-encoding the streams.

You can install ffmpeg with `brew install ffmpeg` after installing [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).

See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files for more information.