# Concatenating AVI files with multiple tracks

Tags: video, video-editing

I have a directory of AVI files that I would like to combine into a single AVI file.  These AVI files come from a dash cam and have two video tracks -- a front camera and a rear camera.

I tried to use the suggestion [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114780/19830) to combine the videos.  Specifically:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i <(for f in $PWD/*.avi;do echo "file '$f'";done) -c copy output.avi
```

This works great for the first (front) video track but completely removes the second (rear) video track.

How can I concatenate these files and retain both video tracks?  Alternatively, is there a way I can specify the video track to concatenate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is demultiplex each file, then concatenate the resulting files. There is a way to do this with the [concat filter](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#filter), but it requires re-encoding everything as it goes.

So you need to do two operations. First, demultiplex. (Note this is untested with ffmpeg, as I don't have any video files to test with, but should theoretically work.)

```
I=0;J=1;for f in $PWD/*.avi;do ffmpeg -i "$f" -map 0:v:0 -codec copy output$I.avi -map 0:v:1 -codec copy output$J.avi && I=$(($I+1)) && J=$(($J+1));done
```

Then you can use the concat demuxer as usual:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i <(for f in $PWD/*.avi;do echo "file '$f'";done) -c copy output.avi
```

Comment: This worked great.  The only change I made is: I=0;J=1;for f in $PWD/*.avi;do ffmpeg -i "$f" -map 0:v:0 -codec copy front$I.avi -map 0:v:1 -codec copy back$J.avi && I=$(($I+1)) && J=$(($J+1));done  and then a corresponding filename change to the concatenation command.  I'd edit, but I don't have the necessary reputation.  Thanks!

Comment: If you do that, you can lose `J=1;` and `J=$(($J+1));` and change `back$J.avi` to `back$I.avi` - with different output filenames, the number can be the same for both.

Comment: Right.  Nice simplification.